# Change format timestamp exception Spring

Tags: java, spring, date, exception

I'm using spring with `@ResponseStatus`to throw an exception like this:

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Unknown task") 
public class TaskNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long taskId;

    public TaskNotFoundException(long taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }

    public long getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }
}
```

I get this kind of response:

```
{
   "timestamp": 1467278537988,
   "status": 404,
   "error": "Not Found",
   "exception": "com.TaskNotFoundException",
   "message": "Unknown Task"
}
```

I'd like to know how to change the timestamp format in order to have ISO 8601 format. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the error response with `@ExceptionHandler` and `@ResponseBody`. For example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(TaskNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
private Message handleMessage(TaskNotFoundException e) {
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setTimestamp(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT));
    message.setError("Not Found");
    message.setStatus(404);
    message.setException("com.TaskNotFoundException");
    message.setMessage("Unknown Task");
    return message;
}
```

`Message` is simple POJO to hold the error response body.

```
public class Message {

    private long timestamp;
    private String error;
    private int status;
    private String exception;
    private String message;

    // getters and setters

}
```

For controller based exception handling, you can add extra `@ExceptionHandler` methods to any controller to specifically handle exceptions:

```
@Controller
class ExceptionHandlingController {

    @ExceptionHandler(TaskNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    private Message handleMessage(TaskNotFoundException e) {
       ...
    }

}
```

For global exception handling, you can use `@ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(TaskNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    private Message handleMessage(TaskNotFoundException e) {
       ...
    }

}
```

More details please check https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I still have a problem. The response header contains the http status `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` of my `@RequestMapping`. If I add `ResponseStatus` to `@ExceptionHandler(TaskNotFoundException.class)`, it's showing the old Spring JSON response.

Comment: I am not sure your actual cause is since `@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)` will return `OK` only if the handling method returns normally. If the handler throws an exception, the annotation does not apply. I think you can try `ResponseEntity<Message>` in your exception handler and explicitly set the http status in `ResponseEntity`.

Comment: I finally found out. I had to get rid off the `reason`attribute in my `@ResponseStatus`

Answer (score 0):

You can use @ExceptionHandler for this and build your own response with ISO 8601 date format :

Below I've attached an example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class SomeController {
...
  @ExceptionHandler(TaskNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
  public @ResponseBody
   Map<String,Object> handleTaskNotFoundException(TaskNotFoundException tnfe,
                                           HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {
     HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
     DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'Z'");
     df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
     String formattedDate = df.format(new Date());
     result.put("8601date", formattedDate);
     ...
     return result;
  }
}
```