# How to change timestamp field format for ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, format, httpresponse

My API returns response body using `org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

I need to change the timestamp field format to a specific format.

What is the property to use in my application.properties file ?

I tried to find it over the web and I found references for other 3rd party lib and not for spring.

And if I can also define the `message` field in some other format I could be great.

Current response body:

```
{
  "timestamp": "Oct 2, 2019 3:24:32 PM",
  "status": 200,
  "error": "OK",
  "message": "Initialization failed. cfgId doesn't exist",
  "path": "/a/b/c/d/init"
}
```

I'm not using any 3rd party library in order to return the json, it's only
`org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity`

I'm looking for a general solution and not per field. I want an application.properties value to fix it.

Comment: the timestamp is part of the object that you send in the body of `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: can you please update some more details? are you using Jackson or Gson? Structure of target class where JSON is being demarshaled?

Comment: If you are using json responses and jackson you can simply annotate your date fields with `@JsonFormat` and the desired format. Please provide implementation details of how you build your json strings.

Comment: I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change format timestamp exception Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119556/change-format-timestamp-exception-spring)

Comment: @roeygol what should be the timestamp format ??

Comment: @AnishB. yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

Comment: @roeygol are you using jackson ??

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [@JsonFormat in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonformat)

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
public Date getCurrentDate() {
    return new Date();
}
```